# How to find the position of a single word of text in a form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, text, position, richtextbox

I'm not sure if this is possible or not. I'm interested in being able to find the (x,y) position of a word of text on a `WinForm`.

For example, in the picture below, I want to be able to pull the (x,y) coordinate of the upper-left hand corner of the letter H in "HERE".

I know how to get the position of textbox, so I can make a rough estimate based off of where the word "HERE" is inside the textbox, but I would like to be able to just ask the program where the word is if that is possible.

Also, if there is a way to get that position, I'd like to be able to get the length and height of the word (Basically I want to know the coordinates of the bounding box of the word "HERE" if possible)

Not sure if this matters, but the textbox is a `richTextBox`, and the textbox is populated from a string array in the `Form1` class.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: But, why would you want to do this?

Comment: I want to position other objects in the form relative to the position of certain words/phrases. I have tried shrinking the textbox so it is only big enough to show the text, then positioning based off of that, but then the text updates and things don't work again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GetPositionFromCharIndex` method, to get position of "HERE" within the `TextBox` or `RichTextBox` (it works for both).

As you probably know, to get position in the window you have to sum this up with position of your `richTextBox`. Like this:

```
int index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf("HERE");
Point textBoxLocation = richTextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
Point windowsLocation = new Point(richTextBox1.Location.X + textBoxLocation.X, richTextBox1.Location.Y + textBoxLocation.Y);
Console.WriteLine("Position in textbox: " + textBoxLocation.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Position in window: " + windowsLocation.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried this code and it isn't working for me. If I understand how this code works, I may have misled you. The string array that populates the textbox only has 3 entries. text[0] = "Select an item from the drop down below", text[2] = "", and text[3] = "I want to find where HERE is". Thus, there is no index of "HERE". As such, the index variable using your code returns an index of -1.

Should I just break the line with "HERE" in it? I presume your code would work then.

Comment: @BrianH If `index` is -1, that means that there is no "HERE" in the code (it's case sensitive)

Comment: ... Yeah ... searched the lower textbox instead of the upper one ... my bad!

Comment: However, now it is returning the point (0,0), which isn't where the word "HERE" is ... ?
I've tried substituting the word "HERE" for different words, and it gets a different index for all the different words, but the point is always (0,0) for all the words I've tried

Comment: Just do: Create empty `WinForms` project. Put there ONLY `richTextBox` and `button`. Paste my code in `button1_Click` event. Open app, type just "HERE" in `richTextBox` and you will MUST HAVE textBoxLocation=(1,1)

Comment: I got it working. The point p was coming back as (0,0), but it looks like the rest of the code executes fine. I commented the Point p = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index); line out and the code works well from what I can see

Comment: @BrianH Look at my edited answer. I may have misled you with those first two lines. Does it work now?